# How to replace the location hash and only keep the last history entry?

Tags: javascript, browser-history, pushstate, jquery-bbq

I'm using the [jQuery BBQ plug-in](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) to track the users progress through the page. However, I only want to create 1 additional entry in the user's history, not one for every hash change.

I've tried the `jQuery.bbq.pushState` and [`merge_mode`](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq-dev/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html#jQuery.param.querystring%28build_url%29) methods, without success: New history entries are still added:

```
jQuery.bbq.pushState({ sort: encodeURIComponent(sort) });
```

I have also tried `location.replace()`, but that doesn't work for Safari 5.1.2.

```
location.replace('#' + encodeURIComponent(sort))
```

What's the cross-browser solution to modify the hash, without adding too much entries to the history?

Comment: Have you already used `replaceState` instead of `pushState`?

Comment: I don't see any such method in the library http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html @Rob W

Comment: I actually meant the [`history.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState().C2.A0method) method. *See also [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js/tree/master/scripts/bundled/html5)*.

Comment: history.replaceState doesn't work in < IE 9, so I'll check out history.js next @RobW

Comment: @RobW, it seems like HTML4 browsers don't allow this functionality to work **and only create 1 entry in the history**. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First, I show the definition of function `replaceHash`, which accepts only one argument: The new location hash. A detailed explanation of the logic can be found at the bottom of the answer.

### Code:

```
// Should be executed BEFORE any hash change has occurred.
(function(namespace) { // Closure to protect local variable "var hash"
    if ('replaceState' in history) { // Yay, supported!
        namespace.replaceHash = function(newhash) {
            if ((''+newhash).charAt(0) !== '#') newhash = '#' + newhash;
            history.replaceState('', '', newhash);
        }
    } else {
        var hash = location.hash;
        namespace.replaceHash = function(newhash) {
            if (location.hash !== hash) history.back();
            location.hash = newhash;
        };
    }
})(window);
// This function can be namespaced. In this example, we define it on window:
window.replaceHash('Newhashvariable');
```

### Function logic

- When [`history.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method) is supported, the function will always replace the current hash, without any side effects.
- Otherwise, a reference (`hash`) to the very first `location.hash` property is created, and the following function is defined:

  1. If `location.hash != hash`, then we know for sure that the history's state is at least past the first page view. We can safely go back in the history, without unloading the page. **`history.back(); // Go back in the history`**.
  2. Then, set the `location.hash` property. If we went back in the history in the previous step, the history entry is overwritten.

  The fallback (last) method may not always replace the history:
  When `location.hash == hash`, either of the following is true:

  1. The hash hasn't changed yet, so it makes no sense to go back to the previous page.
  2. It's possible that the user navigated backwards, to the original page's state. If we use `history.back();`, the page might be unloaded, which is not desirable.

  So, to be **safe**, we **never** unload the page when the hash is equal to the saved original hash.

  Note: It is important to run this code before a hash change. When the hash has already been changed, the script is not reliable any more. The user could have navigated to the very first hash state, which is not equal to the saved `hash`. Consequently, `history.back()` unloads the page.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for - thank you so much for posting this code!

Answer (score 23):

You could use the `replace`-method from `window.location`, without the second `newSubStr`-argument. This works in all known browsers, even oldIE:

```
function replaceHash(hash) {
  return window.location.replace(
    '#' + hash.replace(/^#/, '')
  );
}
```

Note, that if there's a valid element ([as per spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-indicated-part-of-the-document)) in the document, the page will jump/scroll to it.

Comment: not quite, location.replace actually reloads the page

Comment: @makc Could you provide some more details please? What Browser, what version?

Comment: I just tried location.replace(location.href.spli('#')[0]) to lose the hash before ending up here. In chrome@mac, this would reload the page.

Comment: if you just pass hash, it is still saved on history :(